How to know if my composable screen was open trough a deepLink
I have an activity with several composable screens.
Each screen has the feature to be opened with an intent or by user click.
Also, each composable screen has a back arrow.
What I want to do is to know if that composable was opened trough a deep link or the user just clicked in that screen

You can setup extra parameters for all of your screens for detecting the source. When you're navigating from within the application you can set the source parameter to be "in-app" but when you're navigating through deeplink, you can set the parameter to "deeplink". When receiving the deeplink you can have this code in MainActivity:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        val navController = rememberNavController()

        // Handle deep links
        intent?.data?.let { uri ->
            val source = "deeplink"
            navController.navigate(Screen.Detail.createRoute(source))
        }

        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screen.Home.route) {
            composable(Screen.Home.route) {
                HomeScreen(navController)
            }
            composable(Screen.Detail.route) { backStackEntry ->
                val source = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("source") ?: "user"
                DetailScreen(source)
            }
        }
    }
}

The above code will detect the intents from deeplink and set the parameter as "deeplink" before navigating to you desired screen. In the screen you can check the source like this:
@Composable
fun DetailScreen(source: String) {
    val isOpenedFromDeepLink = source == "deeplink"

    // Your UI logic
    if (isOpenedFromDeepLink) {
        // Handle deep link specific logic
    } else {
        // Handle user navigation specific logic
    }
}


Thanks!
I want in the activity to create a boolean variable and pass it to my composable that has the NavHost. And inside that I see that boolean trough the arguments of the navigation.
I will continue to try to do that, but thanks again!

Code snippet:
`private fun handleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
intent?.let {
navController.handleDeepLink(it)
it.data.also {
DeepLinkStateHolder.setDeepLink(true)
}
}
}
}
object DeepLinkStateHolder {
private val _isDeepLink = MutableStateFlow(false)
val isDeepLink = _isDeepLink.asStateFlow()
fun setDeepLink(value: Boolean) {
    _isDeepLink.value = value
}`

